# Plotting randomly generated points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, random

I am trying to generate 100 random points of variables `mf1` and `msc1` and calculate `mhiggs`. I want calculated values and corresponding random points to be printed together in human readable form. Also, What can be done if I want to choose only certain values of `mhiggs` and want to print those values along with corresponding random points? How can these generated points (for a specific value of `mhiggs`) be plotted?

```
mf1 = RandomReal[{100, 2000}, 100];
msc1 = RandomReal[{0, 2000}, 100];
For[j = 1, j < 10, j++,
Print[mhiggs[1, mf1[[j]], msc1[[j]]]]]
```

Comment: use `Table` not `For` and `Print`

Comment: you could use `MapThread[mhiggs[1,#1,#2]&,{mf1,msc1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give the definition for the function `mhiggs`, so I will make up my own to illustrate the procedure.

```
mf1 = RandomReal[{100, 2000}, 100];
msc1 = RandomReal[{0, 2000}, 100];

(* Function simply adds its argument. Replace this with your definition. *)
mhiggs[x_, y_] := x + y
```

Then you can use `Table` to get value of function along with its arguments for first 10 points (or some other range). Results can be neatly printed with `TableForm`.

```
list = Table[
  {mhiggs[mf1[[i]], msc1[[i]]], mf1[[i]], msc1[[i]]},
{i, 1, 10}];
TableForm[list, TableHeadings -> {None, {"mhiggs", "mf1", "msc1"}}]
```

`Select` with appropriate second argument is the way to extract only the interesting points (e.g. points (lists) where the first argument is larger than some threshold).

```
Select[list, #[[1]] > 2400 &]
```

To calculate values of `mhiggs` for all generated random points you can also write more concisely.

```
list = MapThread[
  {mhiggs[#1, #2], #1, #2} &,
  {mf1, msc1}
  ]
```